# Laravel resource route with slashes in uri

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

In laravel 5.4 what is the best way to declare a resource route with slashes in the uri section?

For example in my routes/web.php I have:

```
Route::resource('/admin/settings', 'SettingController');
```

But if I have also this:

```
Route::resource('/settings', 'SettingController');
```

then laravel creates the same names for the routes which is in both cases `settings.index, settings.store, settings.create` etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use dot notation:

```
Route::resource('admin.settings', 'SettingController');
```

Comment: Yes that did work out. I didn't know that I shouldn't use slashes in the uri argument of resource function.

Answer (score 0):

Dot in resource instead of slash.

```
 Route::resource('Demo.setting','DetailsController');
```